# Can't overwrite variable value in django signal

Tags: python, django

Why when I set `active_template = home.template` in django signal everything looks fine untill I "click" again "save" button in admin panel. Then active_template variable is set again to 0. Shoudn't be overwrite when I run signal again? I try this with normal function and it work so I guess the problem is signal.

model:

```py
class Homepage(models.Model):

    choice_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

    TEMPLATE_TYPE = [
        (choice_dict['one'], '1'),
        (choice_dict['two'], '2'),
        (choice_dict['three'], '3'),
        (choice_dict['four'], '4'),
        (choice_dict['five'], '5'),
    ]

    template = models.IntegerField(choices=TEMPLATE_TYPE, null=True, blank=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
```

signal

```py
def default_value(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    test = ['test','test1','test2']
    home = Homepage.objects.first()
    active_template = 0
    if home.template and active_template != home.template:
        Homepage.objects.filter(pk=2).update(content=test[home.template])
        active_template = home.template

post_save.connect(default_value, sender=Homepage)
```

Comment: `active_template` is just a local variable in your signal - how should the Django Admin even know about it?

Comment: Where and how are you displaying active_template in the admin?

Comment: ```active_template``` is just a local helper variable and I don't use it anywhere outside signal. My goal is to run ``if``` statement if choosen ```template``` in model is not active. So when I change any field in model but field ```template``` will stay the same ```if``` statement will not execute.

Comment: But as you just said, it's a local variable. So I don't know why you expect it to persist. It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to fill ```content``` TextField with some data (which is stored in variable) depends on ```template``` field (if is not empty fill ```content``` field with data). So when I'm creating Homepage object in admin panel and choise any```template``` signal will execute ```if``` condition. But when I want to edit the same object after it's created and ```template``` field is not empty anymore I don't want signal to execute ```if``` statement. If this solution is wrong please give me some advice how to do that.